# Takes long to load hidden Quicktime embeds

Tags: javascript, quicktime

I have about 5 Quicktime movies that I hide with jQuery when the site first loads. I noticed when I put the site online that when I open the site it takes 5-10 seconds to show any content. Sometimes I even get a "beach ball" cursor as if the browser is frozen.

It's not like all the videos need to be preloaded before the site can load, and it feels more like a processor freeze. What exactly is happening here and how can I kill this load time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should be because at that time Quick Time is activating the QuickTime plugin. It should depend on Browser capabilities and QuickTime plugin.

What you can do, use jQuery's `load` method and inject quick time codes after page is completed and parse the code.